# Deploying to appEngine auth

Tags: maven, google-app-engine

I use the following command to deploy a java app to AppEngine standard for the first time:

```
mvn appengine:update
```

Then I get an output saying I should use the following use the following url to authenticate. Pressing the URL opens the web browser and displays the following:
[image]

What application and where should I switch to?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to copy the code (more like hash) into the console I was using to deploy.